# Sqlite3 dump database through PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to be able to dump a whole sqlite database to a file (database.sql) so as to use it as a backup. The problem is that exec() in PHP doesn't seem to run correctly the ".dump" command as it gives only "COMMIT;" as a result and not the whole text:

```
$db = new SQLite3('checks_db.db');
$results=$db->exec('.dump');
$content=$results->fetchArray();
```

If I run it from sqlite3 it gives both the schema and the insert insrtuctions with the data. 
Perhaps I should also mention that the database has 777 permissions.
Can anyone write an example of the syntax of the '.dump' command in php-sqlite3?

Comment: Show your `exec()` command.

Comment: The PHP script goes as `$db = new SQLite3('checks_db.db'); $results=$db->exec('.dump'); $content=$results->fetchArray(); ` but I get nothing in $contents.

Comment: And what is the result (in `$content`)?

Comment: I get this answer: `Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near ".": syntax error in C:\Documents and Settings\Filippos\wapache\htdocs\checks\save_db.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in C:\Documents and Settings\Filippos\wapache\htdocs\checks\save_db.php on line 5
`

Comment: If I run it in ubuntu I get only the `COMMIT;` which is the last line of the data I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQLite database does not have a `.dump` command.

The [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) has a `.dump` command.
To be able to use it, you would have to execute that tool; something like this:

```
exec('sqlite3 /some/where/checks_db.db .dump', $output);
```

The easiest way to make a backup would be to copy the database file itself, but using the shell's `.backup` command would be safer.

Comment: so there isn't any way to produce such a file? I thought I could do it in many steps with an insert command for evey line of results etc but still there is the problem of creating tables - I believe that `.schema` would be like `.drop`...

Comment: There is a way; it is to execute the `sqlite3` tool.

Comment: yeah but how do I do this via PHP?

Comment: You should not copy database file itself, at least not in working environment (i.e. running website). These copies will not be atomic. Please read section 1.2 in [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).

Comment: @VincasDargis Please note that this does not copy the file itself, it accesses the database with the normal API.

Comment: @CL. I had in mind comment "_The easiest way to make a backup would be to copy the database file itself._" . Just a side note to be cautious.

Comment: @CL Beware, copying the database file is a recipe for trouble. If the file is corrupted it may appear to be fine at first, but when you restore the backup you may find out that the data is not there anymore.

Comment: exec('sqlite3 database.sqlite .dump > database.sqlite.sql'); // <- that worked for me!!!